# Input validation conundrum

Tags: c++, validation

I just wrote a pretty simple input validation algorithm.  I thought it was pretty good, but when I was testing it I saw something I didn't understand.  Here is the code first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Simple Menu"
    << "\n\t\t1. Input"
    << "\n\t\t2. Exit" << endl;

string input = "";

int myNum = 0;

char myChar = {0};

do
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid menu option: ";
    getline(cin,input);

    if (!(stringstream(input) >> myNum))
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid menu option: ";
        getline(cin,input);
    }           

}while(myNum < 1 || myNum > 5 || input.length() != 1);

cout << "\nThe menu option you entered is: " << myNum << endl << endl;

return 0;       
}
```

Turns out, if I put .1 in as a choice it asks me to enter a valid option, which is good.  However, if I enter 2 (a valid option) immediately following entering .1, it still reacts as though I put in a bad value.  Here is the console window for such an event:

```
Simple Menu
                1. Input
                2. Exit
Please enter a valid menu option: .1
Please enter a valid menu option: 2
Please enter a valid menu option: 2

The menu option you entered is: 2

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any idea why this is?

Comment: p.s.  I know the myChar doesn't have to be there, I forgot to delete it from the code after I was done messing around.

Comment: Follow the execution path. When you enter 2 the first time, it's in the `if` block, and there's no conversion in there.

Comment: By the way, that will accept `2ab` as input. I prefer `boost::lexical_cast`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code:

```
do
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid menu option: ";    // first prompt
    getline(cin,input);                              // you enter .1

    if (!(stringstream(input) >> myNum))
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid menu option: ";// second prompt
        getline(cin,input);                          // this data is discarded
    }           

}while(myNum < 1 || myNum > 5 || input.length() != 1);
```

Change to:

```
do
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid menu option: "; // first prompt
    getline(cin,input);                           // .1

    if (!(stringstream(input) >> myNum)) continue;// if parsing fails loop back
} while(myNum < 1 || myNum > 5 || input.length() != 1);
```

Simplify further to:

```
myNum = -1;
do
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid menu option: "; // first prompt
    getline(cin,input);                           // .1

    stringstream(input) >> myNum;
} while(myNum < 1 || myNum > 5);
```

Comment: You could make it even simpler by giving myNum a default (and invalid) value, like -1, and getting rid of the check inside the loop (since the loop will keep on going until you enter a valid value anyway).

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing as continue!  That'll really come in handy.  Also, your logic on the second version is really good, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Trace out your logic, its doing what you told it todo. What you want is something like so

```
string input;
int myNum = -1;
while(myNum < 1 || myNum > 5 || input.length != 1){
    cout << "Please pick a valid menu options: ";
    getline(cin,input);
    stringstream parser(input);
    if(! (parser >> input )){
       input.clear();
       myNum = -1;
    }  
}
```